# document.body.innerHTML embedded in SharePoint clearing page, how to print result and stop script?

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I need to request users accessing a SharePoint page using IE 11 (in Windows 7) to access the same page using Firefox as I'm embedding Office 365 videos which in IE 11 play using Flash and we weed to use Firefox for HTML5 to improve video quality.

Let me preface that I'm no scripting expert. The example below is an example I found that I modified so only for IE 11 is there a result. I can get the script to run by placing the script in the body of a basic HTML file.

If I try loading it into SharePoint as either an embedded script or HTML file loaded into an iFrame at the top of the page, where I wish the message to appear, it clears the page.

I understand enough to know that the function `document.body.innerHTML` will clear whatever appears after it in the page body. It doesn't do so when I load the script in a plain HTML page but does in SharePoint. And the only way to fix the issue is to replace the page with an earlier version to remove the offending script.

I'm now assuming that the script should be embedded at the base of the SharePoint page, after all other content has been loaded and then load the result, in this case `browserName = 'This site is best viewed using Firefox';` somehow at the top of the page. To be honest I've no idea on how to achieve this. I've been several similar examples which use an alert function but in this case I want the result to show at the top of the page for those accessing SharePoint using IE 11. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
var browserName;

// Opera 8.0+
if ((window.opr && opr.addons) || window.opera || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0))
browserName = "";

// Firefox 1.0+
if (typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined')
browserName = "";

// At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0)
browserName = "";

// Internet Explorer 6-11
if ((/*@cc_on!@*/false) || (document.documentMode))
browserName = 'This site is best viewed using Firefox';

// Edge 20+
if (!(document.documentMode) && window.StyleMedia)
browserName = "";

// Chrome 1+
if (window.chrome && window.chrome.webstore)
browserName = "";

document.body.innerHTML = browserName;
```

`

[UPDATE]
With my limited skills I got an okay result by replacing

```
document.body.innerHTML = browserName;
```

With the following,

```
document.write(browserName);
```

Of course it would be better overall to just check for IE but I found it simpler to just leave the output for the other browser types empty

Answer (score 0):

IE11 supports the HTML5 video tag (at least when it's not running in compatibility mode and thus emulating IE8), so this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#66378). Your efforts might be more fruitfully spent trying to get the video to play without using Flash in IE11 (or configuring your page so that it doesn't force IE to display in compatibility mode).

With that said, there are several different ways to insert HTML onto a page via JavaScript without overriding any existing content.

#### insertAdjacentHTML

One way would be to grab an existing element on the page (using `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementById`) and then insert the desired HTML adjacent to that element using `element.insertAdjacentHTML`.

Note that you could also directly modify an element that's already on the page after grabbing it with `document.querySelector` by editing its `innerHTML` property, although it's usually a better idea to leave that untouched and just add your own HTML.

#### document.createElement() and document.body.appendChild()

Another approach would be to create your own HTML element via `document.createElement`, adjust its style attributes so that it's absolutely positioned near the top of its parent, and then append it to document's body.

Check out the example snippets below to see those approaches in action.

```js
document.getElementById("insert").onclick = addByInsertion;
document.getElementById("create").onclick = addByCreation;

function addByInsertion(){
  // grab an existing element near the top
  var div = document.querySelector(".MainContent"); 
  
  // insert your HTML near the element
  div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin","<h1>Your Special Message Here</h1>");
}

function addByCreation(){
  // create an element
  var announcement = document.createElement("h1"); 
  
  // add styling to the element so it shows up at the top
  announcement.style.position = "absolute";
  announcement.style.top = 0;
  announcement.style.border = "2px solid black";
  announcement.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  announcement.innerHTML = "Your Special Message Here";
  
  // append the element to the body of the document
  document.body.appendChild(announcement);
}
```

```html
<div>Existing Content</div>
<div class="MainContent">
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="insert">insertAdjacentHTML</button>
  <button id="create">document.createElement</button>
</div>
```